# HTML5/CSS3 proprely lining up elements

Tags: html, css, web, element

I am building a website with 3 "main" elements, a banner, a Nav section and the content section (see joint image) [Site Plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc7CP.png). However, I would like to know what is the "proper" way to line up the different elements on a vertical (I mean left - right) axis using CSS propreties. I have investigated the static, absolute, relative attributes but nothing quite worked. I'm obviously doing it wrong but what should I do?

Here's my CSS code

```
     @font-face { font-family: Florsn17; src: url('fonts/Florsn17.ttf'); } 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px gray; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px white; 
}

body {
    font-family:Arial,Helvettica,sans-serrif;
    background-image:url("images/background.jpg");
    background-color:black;
}

header {
    background-color:black;
    height:300px;
    width:720px;
    float:center;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div#center {
    background-color:#333;
    background-image:url("images/menuBarBackground.jpg");
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1px;
    width:720px;
    height:86px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    margin-right:auto;
}

li#item_Home {
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-top:-16px;
}

ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:16px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-left:30px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

.current {
    background-color:#111;
}

#mainSection{
    background-color:#262626;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:-112px;
    width:720px;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#mainSection article {
    font-family: Florsn17,Arial,Helvettica,sans-serrif;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
    line-height:1.5em;

}

#video {
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#googleMapScreenCap {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be super helpful having a JS fiddle so we can accurately assess what you are trying to ask. At the very least, we will need to see the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `header` is the banner, `div#center` is the nav and `#mainSection` is the content. First of all, I saw that all of them have, for example, `width:720px;` you can create a wrapper(div) that contains all of them, or a class to give them the same width (and all the attributes that they have in common). The wrapper is the best option. Also, in that wrapper/class you set `margin: 0 auto;` to center them.

Comment: You guessed right, sorry I wasn't more clear about that... Anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a **container div** that contains all the other HTML elements, then add the following CSS rule to center the container and it's containing elements:

**HTML**

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <!-- header, navbar, etc -->
 </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```